# How did Sidious retrieve his lightsaber after losing it in his battle with Mace Windu, before his battle with Yoda?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

How did Sidious get his lightsaber back after losing it in his battle with Mace Windu and before his fight with Yoda?

Answer (score 26):

**[He didn't.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Sidious'_lightsabers)**

Sidious actually had at least two identical or near-identical lightsabers, which he kept concealed in his office on Coruscant during the Clone Wars era. One in particular, the example he used during the confrontation with Master Windu et al, was kept inside of a statue on his desk and was lost during the confrontation. The one he used in his duel with Master Yoda was a different one that followed the same design.

For the most part, it would seem (according to what we see onscreen) that Sidious preferred to only use one lightsaber at a given time. However, in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* S5E16 "The Lawless", Sidious is shown using two lightsabers at once on Mandalore:
[image]

Comment: Why does his face look like after the confrontation with Mace Windu?

Comment: @Holger It's not really relevant but I'm pretty sure it doesn't. His face is pretty much the same as in his other appearances in the show, it's just more stylized and craggy compared to Ian McDiarmid's real-life face and kept in perpetual half-shadow by his cowl. It's even foreshadowed by this shot earlier in the episode: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/6/65/PalpatineSensesMaul-TL.png/revision/latest?cb=20131025200407

Comment: Confirmed on the Star Wars website; https://web.archive.org/web/20170504161019/https://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/the-lawless-trivia-gallery - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpQbG.png

Comment: Just a note, his post-Windu confrontation face is his real face, a result of corruption from using the dark side. The facade he projects as the Senator/Chancellor is part of his efforts to blind the Jedi.

Comment: @Derek There's some debate about that. I'm not sure it's been definitively proven.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - It's been debunked. Pablo Hidalgo stated that this was intended metaphorically, in the same way that Bruce Wayne considers Batman as his real self, but nobody (other than him, maybe) actually thinks that's the case.

Comment: @Valorum Ah you mean that Palpatine's just like "I looked just like Ian McDiarmid for decades until I got zapped hard enough, but this wizened face is how I really OUGHT to look so I'm gonna keep it"? Kinda like his "I'm gonna use a walking stick to make people think I'm just some decrepit old man but I've totally got a lightsaber and space wizard powers under my robe..." thing?

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - I think he views his Palpatine *persona* as his mask, not his literal face.

Comment: @Valorum Ah I gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Leland Chee spoke to this in [*Star Wars Insider #122*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_122).

> **Q: During his duel with Mace, you see Palpatine's lightsaber falling out the window. Does he build another one before his duel with Yoda? Did he have a lot of lightsabers or did he somehow secure the other one?**
>
> **Ask Lobot:** The *Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith* novelisation by author Matt Stover embellishes on the scene where Mace Windu fights Palpatine describing how Mace cuts Palpatine's lightsaber in half. So it's clearly not the same lightsaber.
>
> For his confrontation with Yoda, Stover describes the appearance of Palpatine's second lightsaber as follows: *"From the shadows of a black wing, a small weapon - a holdout, an easily concealed backup, a tiny bit of treachery expressing the core of Sith mastery - slid into a withered hand and spat a flame-colored blade of its own."*
>
> So yes, there is another.